# Configure Spring with JNDI and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jndi

I tried to use this configuration in order to setup Spring with Hibernate 5 and JNDI. But during startup I get errors.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextDatasource {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.database.models");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() throws NamingException {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
          = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
          "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
          "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() 
      throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em 
          = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/production_gateway");
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Configured POM dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when I run the code I get error during startup:

```
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
```

What is the proper way to configure JNDI? Probably I need to remove some of the Java methods? I want to use Hibernate 5.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or not? Also your dependencies are a mess you are mixing hibernate versions never do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that there is no one who provides you with the JNDI resource
you need a servlet container(tomcat) or application server (weblogic, websphere ecc) that provide you a jndi context

for tomcat example to take through jndi you need specify a datasource configuration
in context.xml 
example

```
<Resource
  name="jdbc/production_gateway"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="30"
  maxWait="10000"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
  username="username"
  password="secret"
/>
```

alternative you can define the datasource using spring without taking it with jndi

Comment: I use Wildfly. Do you know can I remove for example ocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean? Because I got the code from two examples.